# Problems with using Log4j 2 in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging, log4j, log4j2

I just migrated all the java.util.logging codes to log4j in my GAE/J app however I am getting this error:

```
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.management.ManagementFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.OnStartupTriggeringPolicy.<clinit>(OnStartupTriggeringPolicy.java:33)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginManager.decode(PluginManager.java:222
```

Is there a work-around for this?

The dependency for the Log4j is through:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.onami.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.onami.logging.log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you see the developers guide for details?

Comment: Details of the error?

Comment: The error message is quite clear - OnStartupTriggeringPolicy references ManagementFactory - which isn't allowed on GAE.  I don't know much about Log4j 2 - is there a way in your config to disable the OnStartUpTriggeringPolicy or use a different implementation which doesn't use the MX beans stuff e.g. remove <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable JMX in log4j2 by setting system property: `log4j2.disable.jmx=true`.
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/jmx.html

Comment: I've added a system property <property name="log4j2.disable.jmx" value="true" /> in appengine-web.xml but still get the exception about the ManagementFactory.

Comment: Can you post your configuration? Can you avoid using OnStartupTriggeringPolicy in your configuration? I've raised a log4j2 JIRA ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-379

Comment: Marcel, log4j2 now has a fix for this in trunk. This fix will be included in the next (and probably last) beta, beta-9.

Comment: Update: Beta-9 does not correctly solve this issue. There is another solution available in trunk now. It would be great if anyone with access to GAE could verify that with Log4J trunk logging works in GAE.